# How to solve this problem in Spivak Calculus?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is any set of real numbers, define a function $C_A$ as follows: $C_A(x)  = 1$ if  $x \in A, 0$ if $x \notin A$. Find expressions for $C_{A \cap B}$ and $C_{A \cup B}$ and $C_{\Bbb R \setminus A}$, in terms of $C_A$ and $C_B$

I'm unsure what im supposed to do here. I think I may have an answer for $C_{A \cap B}$. Is $C_A + C_B$ a valid expression for it? Because I know the domain of that is $A \cap B$. But even if that is the right direction I'm unsure of how to do the others. I would like it if you guys could guide me in the right direction but not fully answer the question please.

Comment: Try examples.  Try $A=B$, say.  In that case $A\cap B=A$.  Does your expression work?

Comment: Well... let's see... Suppose $A=B=\{1\}$.  What is $C_{A\cap B}(0)$?  What is $C_{A\cap B}(1)$?  What is $C_{A}(1)+C_{B}(1)$?  As a hint, "and" acts similarly to multiplication and "or" acts similarly to plus.

Comment: As an aside, did spivak really use $C$?  I haven't read the book, so haven't seen the notation he uses.  Other authors refer to the [same function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) commonly with the symbol $\chi$ or $1\!\!\!1$ or similar.

Comment: Walk through examples with $A=\{1, 2\}$ and $B=\{2, 3\}$.  Check the values of the function you construct at $1, 2, 3, 4$.  That should give you the intuition you need.

Comment: @lulu Thanks this made the question clear.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok thanks a lot I should be able to solve it now. And yes he did use C for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since$$C_{A\cap B}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in A\cap B\\0&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$you have $C_{A\cap B}=C_A\times C_B$. Can you deal with the other questions now?

Comment: Oh ok i see. I understand what im trying to do now thanks.